# hibernate delete row and update all its references to a new row

Tags: java, hibernate

I have in my java model a `class Client` and a `class Invoice` that references one `client object`. In the database i have two clients with names c1 and c2 and two invoices i1 and i2 that reference respectively the two clients `(i1->c1 and i2->c2)`.

After some time the user of the software notices that the clients c1 and c2 are indeed the same person but when saving the second client he just misspelled the name. Now he renames the client c2 to c1.

At this moment i notice that the client c1 exists in the database. What i want to do is update all references that point to c2 to point to c1 and after that delete client c2. What is the best way to do this with hibernate? I use hibernate with annotations.

Thanks

Comment: You need to do that manually, hibernate (nor any other framework or database) will do this update automatically.

Comment: @Augusto thank you for your reply. Well this is what i have done until now but i thought maybe there is a better way that i do not know about. I aslo do an automatic restart of the program after i update all references to make sure hibernate references no old objects.